# Concatenate non empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I  have n number of dataframes which is formed by downloading data from firestore. The number of dataframes depend on number of unique value of a variable.
coming to the question, I want to concatenate these dataframes into one final dataframe. But I want to ignore the empty dataframes. How can I do this?

For example if I have df1,df2,df3,df4. if df3 is empty, I want to concatenate df1, df2 and df4

Comment: if `df3` is empty without column names it will not get concatenated. else you can try `pd.concat([i for i in list_of_dfs if len(i)!=0])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something like using [`.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) attribute:

```
def concat(*args):
    return pd.concat([x for x in args if not x.empty])

df = concat(*[df1, df2, df3, df4])
```